# Динамическая подгрузка данных на страницу

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

В WordPress у меня выводится к примеру 36 последних постов

Пример:

```
<div class=​"post" id=​"post-66">​…​</div>​
<div class=​"post" id=​"post-65">​…​</div>​
<div class=​"post" id=​"post-64">​…​</div>​
и т.д.
```

С верху новые.

Можно ли средствами jquery или AJAX (чем лучше ?) сделать, чтобы отображалась только 18 и кнопка "Показать еще". При нажатии, эти 18 заменяются более старыми.

Сорри, если что то намудрил. Просто мало в этом разбираюсь.

Comment: В статье [Как настроить бесконечную прокрутку WordPress сайта](http://wordpresso.org/tutorials/kak-nastroit-beskonechnuyu-prokrutku-wordpress-sayta/) посмотрите принцип работы. И в статье [Загрузка части контента на WordPress с помощью AJAX](http://dimox.name/downloading-of-the-content-on-wordpress-with-ajax/) - тоже можно найти плоезное.

Comment: @Родион Поляков, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Answer (score 1):

Ajax - это лишь часть jquery.

в самом jquery это естественно есть )

просто сделайте динамическую подгрузку контента

(Надеюсь, это действо объяснять не нужно)

Общая идея - Вы передаете в запросе номер последнего DIV'a и, отталкиваясь от этих данных извлекаете из БД очередные 18, при успехе увеличиваете Вашу контрольную переменную на 18.

Удачного кодинга!
[ya.ru](http://yandex.ru/yandsearch?text=%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%20jquery&lr=35)

Comment: и не влом вам было `<br>` расставлять...